# Shaded triangle (itemize environment, article class)

Tags: beamer, itemize, shapes

I'm wondering how to draw a `beamer` like bullet in the `article` class. I've gotten close using `\renewcommand{labelitemi}{$\triangleright$}` but would like the triangle to be filled in and am not sure whether such as shape exists. I've shown a basic example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\triangleright$}

\begin{document}
\section{How can I make the triangle filled in?}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bullet 1
\item Bullet 2
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\blacktriangleright` from the `amssymb` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\blacktriangleright$}

\begin{document}
\section{How can I make the triangle filled in?}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Bullet 1
    \item Bullet 2
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to take the color in as a parameter? I am looking to the same thing, but sometimes in red, sometimes in blue, etc.

Comment: This is simply done by replacing `{$\blacktriangleright$}` with `{$\color{cyan}{\blacktriangleright}$}` where cyan can be any color of your likings.